# disabling context menu on iframe,when loading pdf for all browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I am not able to disable,context menu in iframe loaded with PDF content , I have tried overlapping div using z-index but not working in IE,also tried basic context menu disabling code used in jquery. Please give the answer which you have tested only.

Comment: is your iframe in same domain as parent?

Comment: Tried iframe in same domain and different domain,for anyone solution is working in IE ,i  am ok.